# How to auto-generate a group of matrices?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have to make a bunch of matrices and since it is way to much I would to like to automatize the process.

I need matrices with three lines:

```
U -fixed- (each matrix should have one at 0.5 step)
n 0 to 1 in 0.001
m 0 to n (for each of the 'n' values)
```

I would appreciate any kind of help, or at least a direction of what to do.

Comment: `M = [U*ones(1, 1001); 0:0.001:1; 0:1000];` Please have a look at the online documentation. Espacially [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) example describes how to do it.

Comment: @ChrisH. Can I concatenate the code like `n =0:0.001:1` and m `0:0.001:n`? Because the simple matrices I know how to do. My challenge is to make m go from zero to n, for each n.

Comment: No, in general you cannot, because `n` will have length 1001 and `m` will be of length `floor(1000*n+1)` . You cannot stack vectors of different length into a matrix. Maybe, what you want is [`linspace()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), e.g. `n = 0:0.001:1; N = zeros(1001); for i=1:length(n); N(i,:) = linspace(0,n(i),1001); end`?

Comment: @ChrisH. Kind of it. Since I have to create hundreds of matrices I was trying to fix two lines and vary the last. `U = 6, n=0.5` then autocomplete the `m` line for its value going from `0` to the correspondent n, like  `n=0.5`.

I guess I'll to make a loop.